# Errors when using 'ControllerAs' but works fine when using '$scope' in ng-repeat checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controlleras

When using '$scope' syntax, checking on individual checkbox correctly outputs its corresponding object name but when applying 'ControllerAs' syntax to same code, checking on individual checkbox abnormally generates error

```
$scope.users = [{.....}] //using $scope syntax
$scope.selected = [];

$scope.exist = function(item) {
  return $scope.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
}
$scope.toggleSelection = function(item) {
  var idx = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);
  if (idx > -1) {
    $scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    $scope.selected.push(item);
  }
}
```

Representation of above code using in ControllerAs

```
vm.users = [{....}] //Using 'Controller As' Syntax
vm.selected = [];

vm.exist = function(item) {
  return vm.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
}
vm.toggleSelection = function(item) {
  var idx = vm.selected.indexOf(item);
  if (idx > -1) {
    vm.selected.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    vm.selected.push(item);
  }
}
```

Error returned in chrome developer tools

TypeError: vm.selected.indexOf is not a function
    at GridController.vm.exist (gridController.js:37)

Demo Controller As, http://plnkr.co/edit/5auLDGbpyDFUcpPxBzNs?p=preview

Demo $Scope, http://plnkr.co/edit/2jz0ieeCWJE6tvzXK69A?p=preview

Please what could be the issue or could this be a bug when Controller As syntax is applied in this context, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `toggleSelection` function is doing a similar job to `ng-model`, except that `ng-model` has a `selected` property for **each** `user` in your `$scope` code, but a **singular** `vm.selected` property in the Controller As version, due to how JavaScript Prototype Inheritance works with primitives.  This is a prime example of where not using a `.` in bindings causes an unexpected result.

The `ng-model` in this case is changing `vm.selected` from an array into a boolean, which is cascading to an error in your `exist` function, which now sees a boolean that doesn't have a `.indexOf` property.

In this case, your `toggleSelection` code is doing what you need for the rest of your code logic, and you don't actually need `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0):

In your plunkr, you bound the `vm.selected` to a checkbox; this tells angular to set it to a Boolean. When you try to call `.indexOf` on it, it fails because checkboxes with ng-model, by default, are either `true` or `false`.

See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D